# Location when on home wifi is wrong; can I disable using known wireless networks to get location?

Tags: location-services

I just moved to a new city and brought my home wifi router with me. Now whenever I'm connected to my home wifi network, Android thinks I'm at my old house! It's extremely frustrating. Is there a way to disable that method of location finding? Or even better, is there a way to get Google to update the location of this wifi network?

I've tried turning off Wi-Fi scanning and renaming my wireless network. What information does Android use to fingerprint a wireless network? Maybe I can change something about the network to make Android think it's a new, unseen network.

Comment: See: [Location Error after moving](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/140455/3573)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose Android is recognizing the WiFi router with it's MAC address. Since this is not easily changeable on most routers (you could do so with a custom firmware like DD-WRT), you can set your Android to use only GPS as a location source as a workaround.

Depending on your Android version, you should be able to do that under  `Settings` - `Security & Privacy` - `Location` - `Mode`. Set it to `Device only`.

Please note that this disables location determination via mobile network so you might experience your GPS being used more often and the accuracy being lower when you're inside a building.