# Phone keeps returning GPS coordinates of a place I haven't been in years

Tags: lineageos, gps, google-play-services, geolocation, location-services

*Not sure if this is the right place to ask this kind of question, so please let me know if this thread should be moved to another SE board.*

#### The problem

For about two years now, I keep getting very weird behavior when having my apps query my GPS coordinates: **apps keep locating my phone at a place I haven't lived or been in years**.

This belongs all sorts of apps that rely on GPS, starting at Organic Maps, Home Assistant, even Google Maps tends to locate me at that certain location.

**The problem only occurs when my phone doesn't find a satellite to acquire accurate GPS coordinates.**

#### Some background information

- I moved from town X to town Y about 3 years ago
- I signed a fresh contract with my internet provider using only my new address (in town Y)
- When moving, I had a Galaxy S9 with "stock" Samsung Android installed on it, connected to my Google account which had my old physical address saved. Back then, GPS tracking worked like a charm
- at some point after moving, I decided to install /e/OS (for privacy reasons obviously; fork of LineageOS) and get rid of everything connected to Google
- I even deleted my Google account and changed my real name and address inside my Google account before deleting it
- after installing /e/OS, I used microG to have a *random* Google account (necessary for Google Play Services) for usability reasons
- eventually, I decided to buy a new mobile (Galaxy S10e) purging everything and installing /e/OS as well before connecting it to any possible internet account
- I bought a new pre-paid cell phone card which is registered with my new address (town Y)

So basically, I changed my place of residence, changed mobile phone cards, changed mobile phone, changed internet contract, changed my mobile operating system and purged my Google account (and didn't even once connect it to my current mobile phone), thus my phone should be **unable** to have **any** information about my old flat's address, or is there something I left out here?

When moving outside or driving (or being navigated through Organic Maps, for example), apps sometimes locate me at that same location in the beginning, but when getting a good GPS signal, it changes to my real location.

It seems like that certain old address from town X is somehow stored in my phone or location history or somewhere else, I just can't figure out where it could possibly be stored. I have no accounts linked with my phone which know any of my addresses, **how is this possible**?

I am incredibly grateful for any thought on this, it's driving me crazy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you use a migrating tool from S9 to S10? Are you using Google Maps for navigation?  Is your navigation tool using Google maps? Just buy a burner phone they talk about in movies. All the large companies have huge AI bots tracking you. I  dont think you can escape them. So I  just spread my info as wide as possible. That is, using as many different apps as possible. For example  I  stopped using Google maps on Android 4ish. Told it not to track me. Deleted Location history. Disabled the GPS. Yet, when I  filled up at a petrol station, Google pops up and wants to know if it had a car wash.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. AFAIK, the physical address doesn't really affect GPS/location service. However, location services may also use WiFi or Bluetooth for updating location. Thus, if you're bringing your WiFi router from X to Y, then the old location might be still linked to it. Possibly related/dupe: [Location error after moving](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/140455/44325), [Location when on home WiFi is wrong; can I disable using known wireless networks to get a location?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/200398/44325)

Comment: Thanks for linking to other issues. @RohitGupta, I didn't use any migration tools and I'm not using Google Maps for navigation. I absolutely agree to everything you said. I somehow "solved" the issue by configuring my phone to use location services only by GPS. Still, Even though I'm not using ANY Google services, I have no idea where my old place of residence comes from.